# Edit URL variable in Django (remove first element from path)

Tags: python, django

I have a variable:

```
kid.image_url
```

which stored a url:

```
/media/pics/byson.jpg
```

I want to remove /media so that it contain just:

```
/pics/byson.jpg
```

I have just started to learn django. Any help will be appreciated : )

Comment: Have a look on your `settings.py`

Comment: Are you just looking at how to modify the path?  http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html seems like the info you need... break it apart, delete the part you want gone, and put it back together.

Answer (score 4):

```
 stripped = '/media/pics/byson.jpg'.split('/')[2:]
 kid.image_url = '/'+'/'.join(stripped)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using python os.path.split(path) and os.path.join functions. They work both on Windows and Linux. This way your code would be portable. See [Splitting a Path into All of Its Parts](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/python/0596001673/files/pythoncook-chp-4-sect-16). Below is working code

```
import os, sys

def splitall(path):
    allparts = []
    while 1:
        parts = os.path.split(path)
        if parts[0] == path:  # sentinel for absolute paths
            allparts.insert(0, parts[0])
            break
        elif parts[1] == path: # sentinel for relative paths
            allparts.insert(0, parts[1])
            break
        else:
            path = parts[0]
            allparts.insert(0, parts[1])
    return allparts


image_url = "/media/pics/byson.jpg"
image_url = os.path.join(*splitall(image_url)[2:])
```